# Mac: Setting up SVN for personal development

Tags: svn, macos, textmate

I've seen that i already have both svn and svnserve (and a .subversion dir in my home). svnserve should be svn server, as far as i know, but how can i run it? I need something very basic, not linked to apache or any server, just to version files on my own computer for personal development (svn is integrated with TextMate that i use).

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using git instead. Branches in git are very cheap and easy to use, so you can create a separate branch for each feature and develop them in parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need it only on your own machine, you don't even need svnserve. Just use plain file: urls.

for example, create a repository with:

```
svnadmin create testrepo
```

Then you can access it with the url file:///full/path/to/testrepo/

The .subversion directory in you home folder is only intended for settings.

Answer (score 1):

SVN repositories are typically set up through the command line. There is a freely available book here that goes in depth on how to use Subversion: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

To get a quick start, you can just read this: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch05s02.html

Once you've set up the respository, you can use whatever SVN plugins you desire to access and manipulate the repository - in this case TextMate - and not really need to worry about using the command line to work with subversion.

Answer (score 0):

I have SVN set up on my home computer for personal projects. I access it using file: url's across my home network and it works just fine. I've heard a lot of people say this is a bad idea but I've never heard a clear discussion of why. It works quite well for me. Of course at home I don't have any security issues, as it's unlikely that my daughter has any interest in making unautorized access to my SVN repository.